# ERROR AL QUERER INSTALAR UNA LIBRERIA "BASH.EXE" NO EXISTE

Tags: nodejs, bash, npm

estoy queriendo instalar deasync usando el comando "npm i deasync" y me aparece el siguiente error ->

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\sejo_\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Ya verifique y tengo la ultima version de node y npm y tambien tengo la dependecias que se necesitan.

Alguien que me pueda orientar a solucionar este error?

Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Intenta eliminar la carpeta `node_modules` e intenta de nuevo, o intenta reinstalar nodejs

Answer (score 0):

parece que es porque no tienes instalado GIT, aunque no debería ser una dependencia, para instalar una librería npm

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).